# How to view <asp:LoginName /> markup snippet ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Today, I find myself amidst Microsoft's Visual Studio suite for the first time responsible for ASP.NET C# Web Forms applications at work (I am normally the PhP/Apache/MySQL guy). I am trying to display the LoginName value in a simple webpage and I am not sure how the markup snippets work. My code is this:

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="JohnCSharpWebAppTest1.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
        <h3>Your application description page.</h3>
        <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
        <p>You are: <asp:LoginName runat="server" /></p>
</asp:Content>
```

Which probably you've seen a million times when you create a new web forms app. I don't want the user to login to the app. I want to pick up the local user login name on the computer being used. I am trying to display the asp:LoginName attribute. On the server in IIS -> Sites -> Authentication, I have Windows Authentication enabled, and anonymous auth/ASP.NET Impersonation turned off. But still I'm not sure how these snippets pickup their values. At runtime? When the blank "project" is first built?

Thanks for any suggestions.

-John

Comment: Maybe have a read of a lot of existing documentation on the web. A starting point would be https://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3655706/ASPNET-Tip-Using-the-LoginName-and-LoginStatus-Controls.htm

Comment: The engine knows what the username (assuming you've configured authentication correctly) and the <asp:LoginName> has internal logic to request that the engine provide it the username, which it formats nicely into its HTML, which ends up getting rendered to the response along with the rest of the HTML. Seems like you may need to look into basic Web Forms tutorials if you're going to be doing some work in Web Forms - it'd avoid a lot of basic questions like this.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Mason (auth settings in the app as well as the server). I figured out my problem by dumping .Identity.AuthenticationType & .Identity.IsAuthenticated. Works now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out myself by changing the authentication method when creating a project.